# How to change scale unit with ol.control.CanvasScaleLine(), in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, scale, units

I have a scale control `var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({});` and I can change the scale unit.

However, I would like to know if it is possible to change the unit with com `var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.CanvasScaleLine({})`, as it did not change the unit.

```
var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine({});
map.addControl(scaleLineControl);   

// Add a ScaleLine control 
var scaleLineControl2 = new ol.control.CanvasScaleLine({})
map.addControl(scaleLineControl2);  
    
// Add function to set units
function ChangeScale(){
    scaleLineControl.setUnits(this.value);
    scaleLineControl2.setUnits(this.value);
};
    
document.getElementById("metric").addEventListener('click', ChangeScale);
document.getElementById("degrees").addEventListener('click', ChangeScale);
document.getElementById("imperial").addEventListener('click', ChangeScale);
document.getElementById("nautical").addEventListener('click', ChangeScale);
document.getElementById("us").addEventListener('click', ChangeScale);
```

Comment: It's the same code, but with scaleLineControl2: ```scaleLineControl2.setUnits(this.value);``` but it didn't work

Comment: In fact, it doesn't seem to update right away, only after it changes the zoom

Comment: You may need to call `scaleLineControl.render()` after setting the value

Comment: Please update your question to include the code.